# can't access purchased apps

Tags: applications, google-play-store

I have purchased apps from play store. At xmas, When my daughter got her tablet, I signed into my account and she could download all of the purchased apps. Today we got a new tablet and I am trying to do the same thing but it says I have to buy the apps again. Is there a time limit or device  limit for purchased apps?

Comment: If you have multiple devices and you are logged using same Id, then you can install the app on all of your devices without purchasing the app again and there is no time limit.

Comment: reachrk is correct. You must be using the wrong account.

Answer (score 0):

[Check your purchase history in Google Play Store. If your apps dont show up your using the wrong account](https://play.google.com/store/account)